# Floor of the result of a division

Tags: haskell, division, floor

In Haskell, how can I get the floor of the result of a division between two Integers?

The function would be something like this:

```
floorOfDivision :: Int -> Int -> Int
floorOfDivision x y = x `someFunction` y
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is `div` from Prelude.

```
5 `div` 2 == 2
```

Comment: And do you know how to get the ceil of the result?

Comment: Here's a hint: `(-7) \`div\` 2 = -4`

Comment: Or an alternate hint: ```(7+2-1) `div` 2 = 4```.